# Access the structure arrangement connected to the structure pointer

Tags: c

I am implementing a dual connectivity list. (with one head, right link and left link...)

and I want to create a multi-connection list using that linked list.

so..

```
typedef int element;
typedef struct Node
{
    element id_num;
    element course_num;
    struct Node  *next;
    struct Node  *prev;
} Node;

typedef struct List
{
    Node *head;
} List;

Node *courses[35];
Node *students[500];
```

There is a code as shown above.
If I write the code below

```
List *list = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
list->head = *courses;
```

Can I access each index in the courses array?
If not, how can I?

Multi linked list that I want to implement:
[image: multi linked list that I want to implement.]

Comment: why do you have the same data structure for student and course, thats very odd

Comment: you have not allocated any Nodes yet, only pointers to them. So no matter how you try you cannot access them

Comment: you need to allocate each variable on the arrays `courses` and `students`. Or, you might not make them a vector of pointers (they would be allocated, but would contain invalid values, unless you initialize them)...

Comment: What is the point of a `struct` with one member? Is it because you will expand it later?

Comment: @WeatherVane There's 100 to 149 for courses, 2,000 to 2499 for students.
 I wanted to make each list.

Comment: Well they are in `Node *courses[35]; Node *students[500];` although there are not enough. I still don't understand why a type `List` is a `struct` with  only one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your data design, but the main question seems to be this:

> [Given]
>
> ```
> typedef struct List
> {
>     Node *head;
> } List;
>
> Node *courses[35];
> ```
>
> [and]
>
> ```
> list->head = *courses;
> ```
>
> Can I access each index in the courses array?

`*courses` is equivalent to `courses[0]`.  That is, it is the value of the zero<sup>th</sup> element of the array.  It has the correct type (`Node *`) for the assignment, but ***no***, the value of that pointer conveys no information about the storage location (`courses[0]`) from which it was copied.  Therefore that value does not inherently provide a mechanism to traverse the `courses` array.

Here's an analogous example:

```
int array[] = { 7, 3, 52 };
int i = *array;
```

The initial value of `i` does not provide a mechanism for traversing the elements of `array`.

> If not, how can I?

If you want to traverse the array, you need a pointer (in)to the array, not just the value of one of its elements (even though the elements may themselves be pointers to something else).  I don't really see why you wouldn't uses `courses` directly, but if you want to avoid that then you can use a pointer to it, or to its first element (the latter is syntactically a bit easier):

```
Node **list_heads = courses;
Node *one_head = list_heads[0];
Node *next_head = one_head + 1;
```